# How to use MySQL REGEXP in the WHERE of a JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have two tables A and B
Table A has columns: ID and POST
Table B has columns: ID, POST_ID and UPPERS

I want to select all records where a.POST matches the regex

```
'\\[cd(i|b)?(=[a-z0-9]+)?\\].+\\[/cd(i|b)?\\]'
```

and JOIN table B on a.ID = b.POST_ID where b.UPPERS matches the regex

```
'(\\|[0-9]+\\![0-9]{4}[-]+[0-9]{2}[-]+[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},){1,}'
```

I came up with the following statement but it is not returning any row even when the columns contains the contents matching the regex

```
SELECT a.*,b.* 
FROM a JOIN
     b 
     ON b.POST_ID=a.ID 
WHERE a.POST RLIKE '\\[cd(i|b)?(=[a-z0-9]+)?\\].+\\[/cd(i|b)?\\]' AND
      b.UPPERS REGEXP '(\\|[0-9]+\\![0-9]{4}[-]+[0-9]{2}[-]+[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},){1,}'
```

Summary:

I want to select records where a users has sent contents that matches this regex

```
 '\\[cd(i|b)?(=[a-z0-9]+)?\\].+\\[/cd(i|b)?\\]'
```

and then check if that very post has received at least two ups(or likes) using the regex

```
'(\\|[0-9]+\\![0-9]{4}[-]+[0-9]{2}[-]+[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},){2,}'
```

which can be broken down as simply:

```
a prefix pipe: |
a user id: [0-9]+
an exclamation mark: !
a datetime: [0-9]{4}[-]+[0-9]{2}[-]+[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
and a sufix: ,
NOTE: {2,}  simply to check how many times the match occurs
```

Please can someone point me in the right direction as to what am doing wrong.

Sample table datas:

```
Table A
ID    | POST
23  match found [cd=plain]6h+#gtyr[/cd]
24       match found [cd]65#%gte2!iu[/cd]
25       match found [cdi]*tre&y^g82u[/cdi]
26       no match found *tre&y^g82u
27       no match found rtyure99
28       match found [cdb]aha87ulchr[/cdb]

Table B
ID  |   POST_ID     |   UPPERS

4       24              |98!2018-02-10 22:43:03,
                    |35!2018-02-08 20:42:09,
                                            |3!2018-02-05 02:05:07,

5       26              |2!2018-02-10 22:43:03,
                    |30!2018-02-08 20:42:09,

6       25              |21!2018-02-10 22:43:03,

7       27              |23!2018-02-10 22:43:03,
                    |11!2018-02-08 20:42:09,
```

NOTE: POST_ID in table B is a foreign key referencing ID of table A

Comment: We probably should see sample of your tables' relevant fields. Show a row from  both tables which should be picked up by the SELECT

Comment: I don't really know how to post SQL table fields on SO. However let me see if I can manually type it

Comment: And the rows are picked by each of the queries if you run them separately against each table? Rlike to A and regex to B?

Comment: Do you have the option of changing the tables? Your problem hinges on the fact there is a bunch of information combined as text in some of your columns. Rather than solve the regex problem, which will always be slow, I'd go back and solve the fundamental modeling problem.

Comment: @Gnudiff Yes when I ran the queries separately it behaved as expected but on joining the two conditions in the WHERE clause using AND it doesn't return any result

Comment: @Jerry how do you suggest I remodel such that I can get same result. I need users to make post which may sometimes include some tokens as shown in the first regex above and the system collects upvotes on every post; that is user id  and date time of each user that upvotes for every such post matching the regex and saves them in another table from where i can then count the total upvotes received by every such post

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, I'm actually going to answer the question that lies beneath your actual question. I'm sure we could work through why the regular expression is not working as you expect, but it begs the question: why use regular expressions for such a simple task?

It happens a lot that people first just use a database to stash stuff that is the same format that appears in the code. But if you take a little time to break down your data in a meaningful way, you can unlock a lot of power from humble MySQL.

Think about the question you want this query to answer:

- Which posts that match certain criteria have been upped?

As you already realized, that suggests two tables - one to store information about the posts, and another to store information about who upped them. To make your queries fast and easy, think about which attributes of the information are going to show up in your where clause.

You want posts that are enclosed by certain markup. To make your search more efficient, put the markup tag in its own column:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag` enum('cd','cdi','cdb') DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_value` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

for the data you list above, the table might look something like:

```
+-----+------+-----------+-------------+
| id  | tag  | tag_value | content     |
+-----+------+-----------+-------------+
|  23 | cd   | plain     | 6h+#gtyr    |
|  24 | cd   | NULL      | 65#%gte2!iu |
|  25 | cdi  | NULL      | *tre&y^g82u |
|  26 | NULL | NULL      | *tre&y^g82u |
|  27 | NULL | NULL      | rtyure99    |
|  28 | cdb  | NULL      | aha87ulchr  |
+-----+------+-----------+-------------+
```

It takes a little more work to put your data IN (this is where your regex powers are better applied, as you create the `INSERT`), but now you can do all sorts of things with it quite easily. I used an ENUM for the `tag` column, because that is extra-fast to search on. If you have a large number of tags or don't know what they will all be, you can just use a VARCHAR instead.

So how to you track `UPPERS`? That part gets very easy. All you need is a table with a row for each time someone ups something:

```
CREATE TABLE `uppers` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Currently when someone ups something, you have to go find the relevant record, append new data to it, then save it back. Now you can just slap a record into the table. The time will be set automatically; all you need to insert is the `user_id` and `post_id`. Some of your data might look like:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | post_id | time                |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
|  2 |      98 |      24 | 2018-02-10 15:23:03 |
|  3 |      35 |      24 | 2018-02-10 15:23:23 |
|  4 |      27 |      24 | 2018-02-10 15:23:43 |
|  5 |       2 |      26 | 2018-02-10 15:24:16 |
|  6 |      30 |      26 | 2018-02-10 15:24:28 |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

Now you can harness the power of the MySQL engine to capture all the information you need:

All posts with the desired tags:

```
SELECT * FROM posts where tag IN ('cd', 'cdi', 'cdb')
```

All post with the desired tags and at least one up:

```
SELECT posts.*, uppers.user_id, uppers.time
    FROM posts
    INNER JOIN uppers ON posts.id = uppers.post_id
    WHERE tag IN ('cd', 'cdi', 'cdb')
```

That will return a row for each post-upper combination. The `INNER JOIN` means it will not return any posts that don't have a match in the uppers table. This may be what you are looking for, but if you want to group the ups together by post ID, you can ask MySQL to group them for you:

```
SELECT posts.*, COUNT(uppers.user_id)
    FROM posts
    INNER JOIN uppers
    WHERE tag IN ('cd', 'cdi', 'cdb')
    GROUP BY posts.id
```

If you want to rule out duplicate ups by the same user, you can easily only count unique user id's for each post:

```
SELECT posts.*, COUNT(DISTINCT uppers.user_id)
    FROM posts
    INNER JOIN uppers
    WHERE tag IN ('cd', 'cdi', 'cdb')
    GROUP BY posts.id
```

There are many functions like `COUNT()` you can use to work with the data that gets grouped together. You could MAX(uppers.time) to get the time of the most recent up for that post, or you can use functions like `GROUP_CONCAT()` to put the values together in a long string.

The bottom like is that by breaking down your data into its fundamental pieces, you allow MySQL (or any other relational database) to work much more efficiently, and life gets much, much easier.

Comment: Thanks for this great idea. What made me used that table structure was: since a post can be upped by over 1000 unique users, I thought it would make more sense to only save the user Id and time together in one column and delimit each entry. That way I would save more space on my database by not inserting 1000 redundant id   and post_id. Although as we know this would end up producing complex query structures. So which is actually better? Optimizing and saving unnecessary memory consumption and getting complex query structures or piling up the database with redundant entries for some columns

Comment: if there are thousands of users, it is insane to combine the records. You're not going to take up any more space (remember, those delimiters take up space, too) and those regex queries will destroy you. In fact, storing the timestamps as a string is a huge waste of space. I didn't go into indexes, but with a proper table you can index the columns in your `WHERE` clause and read performance will be even better. All those thousands of users will add up to a few megabytes of information. Unless the whole database is on your phone, that's nothing.

Comment: For perspective, when there are a million rows in your uppers table, it will be about the size of a single image taken with my fancy camera.

Comment: Thanks. Let me start remodelling my structure as a backup plan if  I don't get a way out

Comment: Honestly, it shouldn't be a backup plan. Your scheme uses more memory and is going to be dog-slow. Understand the strengths of the tools you are using and let them work for you.

Comment: Ok I will do just that